# Issues with selectize.js and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selectize.js

In my view i have the following code and i'm trying to get the select box to drop down with the values i send with the callback but unfortunately it does not work.

I was following http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/laravel-shop-tutorial-3-implementing-smart-search/ with slight changes her and there to suite my use case.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var root = '{{url("/")}}';

        $('#testselect').selectize({
            valueField: 'url',
            labelField: 'description',
            searchField: ['description'],
            maxOptions: 10,
            options: [],
            create: true,
            render: {
                option: function(data, escape) {
                    return '<div>' + escape(data.description) + '</div>';
                }
            },
            optgroups: [
                {value: 'description', label: 'description'},
            ],
            load: function(query, callback) {
                if (!query.length) return callback();
                $.ajax({
                    url: root+'/gettimecodes',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        q: query
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        callback();
                    },
                    success: function(res) {
                        console.log(res.data) // Prints my data all well and good.
                        var object = {description:"description"};
                        var array = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
                        var json = {
                            "data":[
                                {"description":"Saab"},
                                {"description":"Volvo"},
                                {"description":"BMW"}
                            ]
                        }
                        // callback(array); // Doesn't work. (Array)
                        // callback(object); // Doesn't work (Object)
                        // callback(json); // Doesn't work (JSON)
                    }
                });
            },
        });
    });

</script>
```

If any one could point me in the correct direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Updated with bashers recomendations.

```
            $('#testselect').selectize({
            valueField: 'description',
            labelField: 'description',
            searchField: ['description'],
            maxOptions: 10,
            options: [],
            create: true,
            render: {
                option: function(data, escape) {
                    return '<div>' + escape(data.description) + '</div>';
                }
            },
            load: function(query, callback) {
                if (!query.length) return callback();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/gettimecodes',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        q: query
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        callback();
                    },
                    success: function(res) {
                        callback(res.data)
                    }
                });
            },
        });
```

The JSON that is returned in the response

```
{"data":[{"description":"Crushed blacks "},{"description":"Crushed     blacks "},{"description":"Example of crushed blacks"},{"description":"Example of crushed blacks and video noise"},{"description":"Example of heavily de-interlaced artfacts on footage during title sequence - As source"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `valueField` does not exist. `url` is not a property of the object you pass. Change `valueField` to `description`. Then let me know a more specific error if you get one. Also remove `optGroups` for now. Keep it basic.

Comment: Hi Basher, thanks for getting back to me I have updated the original question with your recommendations changing the valueField worked I don't know how I miss these things sometimes.

Comment: @DanielPremier yea there's a lot going on with selectize. The documentation is like 80% there - it has everything you need but more examples with different data sources would be helpful when starting out. It's a great combobox, though. Stick with it!